# Oracle SQL: JSON query

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle12c

I have below JSON in 12c Oracle table

```json
[
  {
    "od": "2022-01-01",
    "md": "2022-01-01",
    "di": 2.1
  },
  {
    "od": "2022-02-02",
    "md": "2022-02-02",
    "di": 3.1
  },
  {
    "od": "2022-02-03",
    "md": "2022-02-03",
    "di": 4.1
  }
]
```

**od**= order_date, **md**=modified_date, **di**= discount

Expected output

| od | md | di |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 | 2.10 |
| 2022-02-02 | 2022-02-02 | 3.10 |
| 2022-02-03 | 2022-02-03 | 4.10 |

I tried `JSON_VALUE(ORDER_DATA, '$.di' )` it gives me null

I tried `JSON_TABLE()` as below but then too it gives me null

```
SELECT j.id, jt.di 
  FROM order_date j, 
       JSON_TABLE(
                  j.json_order_data, 
                  '$' COLUMNS (
                                di number(10) PATH '$.di[*]'
                              )
                 ) jt;
```

`JSON_EXTRACT()` does not work in oracle

I have tried that as well, can anyone please help me for this SQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it in this way:

```
SELECT j.id, jt.di 
  FROM ORDER_DATE j, 
       json_table(j.JSON_ORDER_DATA, '$[*]' 
        COLUMNS (
          di number(10) PATH '$.di'
        )) jt;
```